# NodeJS best practices: Errors for flow control?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, conventions

In Node.js, should I use errors for flow control, or should I use them more like exceptions?

I'm writing an authentication controller and some unit tests in Sails.js, and currently, my registration method checks to see if a user with the same username exists. If a user already exists with the username, my model method calls its callback arguments with a new Error object, like so:

Model:

```
exists: function (options, cb) {
    User.findOne({
        where: { username: typeof options === 'Object' && options.username ? options.username : options },
    }).exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        if (user) return cb(new Error("A user with that username already exists."));
        cb(null, !!user);
    });
},
```

Controller:

```
User.exists(req.body.user.username, function (err, exists) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error: ", err);
    return res.status(409).json({
      message: err
    });      
  }

  User.create(req.user).then(function (data) {
    res.status(201).json({
      user: data
    });
  });
});
```

Is this best practice? I'm not sure if node conventions favor errors for exceptional cases, or for flow control. I'm thinking I should rewrite this, but I want to know conventions before I do so. I think I've seen some examples written this way in Sails. Thanks!

Comment: A much simpler way is to flag the `username` as unique in the model schema and simply use the error Mongoose returns in your `User.create()` controller to respond with a 409. This is a more optimistic approach because if the user doesn't exist and its a valid request, you're not hitting the DB twice for no reason.

Comment: @jibsales That does make sense - but then, what happens if there's a different error that would necessitate a 500 response? In languages like C#, there are different kinds of exceptions and you can check for that type. I know that I could do something like that in Node if I wanted to, but is that common practice? The decision I make now will affect the way I build the rest of the application. Based on your comment, it seems as though Node uses errors for flow control instead of exceptional situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is good for Express, but in Sails controllers you should not be calling `next`; best practice is to always return a response.  In most example Sails code you won't even see `next` as an argument to a controller action function.  Also note that Sails comes with some [default response methods](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses?q=default-responses) built right into the `res` object, such as `res.serverError` and `res.badRequest`, as well as [`res.negotiate`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/res/res.negotiate.html) which will attempt to route the error to the appropriate handler for you based on the status code.  So your example could be tweaked as:

Model:

```
exists: function (options, cb) {
    User.findOne({
        where: { username: typeof options === 'Object' && options.username ? options.username : options },
    }).exec(function (err, user) {
        // res.negotiate will default to a 500 server error
        if (err) return cb(err);
        // res.negotiate will just output the status code and error object
        // as JSON for codes between 400 and 500, unless you 
        // provide a custom view as api/responses/badRequest.ejs
        if (user) return cb({
          status: 409, 
          message: "A user with that username already exists."
        });
        cb(null, !!user);
    });
},
```

Controller:

```
User.exists(req.body.user.username, function (err, exists) {
  // Let Sails handle those errors for you
  if (err) {return res.negotiate(err);}

  User.create(req.user).then(function (data) {
    res.status(201).json({
      user: data
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Marked this answer correct - while the other one is good, this is Sails-specific. For the record, I ended up doing something similar, but I created my own Error types by extending Error, and I'm checking for the type using Bluebird promises.

Answer (score 1):

Node (or Javascript really) can throw errors on exceptions by using the keyword `throw`:

```
if (something_went_wrong) {
  throw new Error('Doh!');
}
```

You can also add additional parameters to the default Error object to give more semantic meaning to your errors in your program. With that said, you wouldn't want to throw an error in your route handler because this would crash the process and your server.

When using route handlers in Sails (or express really), you most certainly should check the type of error and respond to the client accordingly.

```
// -- Route handler
app.get('/something', function (req, res, next) {

  DB.create({ username: 'user' }, function (err, docs) {

    if (err) {

      // This checks to see if we have a unique error from MongoDB
      // and send the appropriate response to the client
      if (err.code === 11000 || error.code === 11001) {
        return res.send(409); // or return res.json(409, {message: "User exists"});
      }

      // Any other error type is assumed to be an internal error so we pass it
      // down the chain to the error handler middleware
      return next(err);

    }

    // This is a client error, not an internal error so we respond to the client
    // with the appropriate client error type
    if (docs.length === 0) return res.send(404);

    if (user.notAuthorized) return res.send(403);

    res.send('All Good');

  });

});
```

Notice that in the case that the DB responds with an internal error, we pass to the `next()` function which is picked up by error handling middleware down the chain. Any middleware with an arrity of 4 is defined as error handling middleware. Sails probably has some default error handler, but you can probably also override it — you'll need to check the appropriate docs for this information as I prefer the control I gain by using Express alone.

Comment: I see. So in this case, I can use errors for flow control, but I need to check the error code or type or name - which means that I've got to figure out what types of errors Mongo or Sails might throw. I think I'm making progress on this fetch quest.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Errors-for-flow-control in the sense that `err` values mean there was an error. Whether or not *you* use it for flow control is a different issue. Also consider that promisifying libraries make Node conventions go away in favor of normal promise semantics.

Comment: @DaveNewton Indeed. Sails includes [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) by default and I was thinking about using it, actually, as I really prefer the promise pattern. However, Bluebird provides a `catch()` method for its errors, which (although awesome) still means I have to check error names and types.