# NodeJS - What's the deal with throwing errors as a means of control flow?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

This question is similar, but answers are specific to sails: [NodeJS best practices: Errors for flow control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384982/nodejs-best-practices-errors-for-flow-control)

I come from a background working on REST APIs in C#. In C#, when there was an operational "error" (I'm intentionally using error in quotes), we just returned a constant or key to a lookup table of messages. Depending on the message that was returned, the routing layer would return an appropriate status code to the user (200, 404, etc.).

Take logging in. Consider that someone logs into a server, and the account does not exist. This is not an unusual thing to happen, so it doesn't make much sense to throw an error.

Now, I'm writing Node applications and I'm frustrated. It seems like common practice is to just throw errors everywhere when anything unexpected happens. This makes sense for things like the database failing to retrieve an account which is known to exist, or for catching syntax errors. But for something like a user entering the wrong username/password, throwing an error seems like overkill.

Then consider a case where you have error-reporting middleware. For syntax errors, you might want to log a stack trace, when you would never want to do that for something like a wrong password. By using errors for control flow, a user entering a bad password could be using up the same server resources as logging a critical database exception. You could extend the Error class and switch on the type of error, but that seems sloppy.

Finally, some solutions just directly return ExpressJS reponses with status codes, but I don't always want the same status code for every case where a user isn't found in the database. Maybe I want to return a 404 for a user profile page, and a 400 for a failed login.

Has anyone else faced this problem, and if so, how have you handled it (pun intended)?

### UPDATE

Here's some code to demonstrate what my solution would look like.
I've invented a new class called `Goof`, which is like an error but it is used in situations where it is a likely outcome. For example, bad login credentials would be a type of `Goof`:

```
// constants.js.
const WRONG_PASSWORD = 1;
const USERNAME_DOES_NOT_EXIST = 1;

// goof.js.
class Goof {
    constructor(message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

// Inside express route.
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;
const result = await signInUser(username, password);
if(typeof(result) === Goof) {
    if(result.status === constants.WRONG_PASSWORD) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
        return;
    }

    if(result.status === constants.USERNAME_DOES_NOT_EXIST) {
        res.sendStatus(400)
        return;
    }

    else {
        throw new Error('A Goof was returned but not handled properly');
    }
} else {
    res.json(result);
}
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of this over throwing and catching errors?

Comment: Note that there's at least a bit of difference between throwing an error in an `async` function, and throwing an error in a normal synchronous function. An `async` error will result in a rejected Promise which can be caught with `.catch` (`Promise` method), whereas a sync error will result in something that can only be caught with `try/catch` (somewhat different)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think throwing errors is used for control flow--essentially no code I use does this. There's a reason the original async stuff returns "err" to the callbacks when there's an error--because they're not using exceptions as flow control. That said, one reason people do it is because of how some people structure their code--deeply-nested callbacks or async functions just often unwind the stack many levels; with exceptions you just put the catch where you need it instead of continually passing it back up.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks for the comment. Can you provide an example of how you would handle situations like I've described? Most of the code that I've seen uses the anti-pattern that I've mentioned, and I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: @StookOverflook The same way you would in any other language.

Comment: It might seem obvious, but after looking at line after line of code littered with try-catch blocks, that is music to my ears. Sometimes it's easy to get caught up in the language features and forget that I can write my code however I want. Thanks :)